# Why is test command showing ERROR for the echo shell-builtin in bash?

Tags: bash, echo

`test -e echo ; echo $?` is giving the output `1`(False) instead of `0` (True).

`test -e FILE` returns True `0` if FILE exists else False `1`.

Then why is `test -e echo` returning `1`?

Comment: `test` doesn't look for commands, only files, and it doesn't do path lookup.

Comment: @chepner Thank you so much. Should I delete my question now? Just asking. I am new to this platform.

Comment: No, just accept choroba's answer.

Comment: See: `help test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the file `echo` doesn't exist in the current directory.

Try creating it:

```
touch echo
test -e echo && echo Exists.
```

If you want to check `/bin/echo`, you either need to change the directory to `/bin`, or specify the full path.

```
cd /bin
test -e echo
```

or

```
test -e /bin/echo
```

Comment: Oh I see. So it doesn't find the executable in PATH? Am I correct?

Comment: Correct; `test` has nothing to do with command lookup.

Comment: Exactly. Use `type` to find commands, functions, aliases, and shell builtins.